# Difference between numbers present in two different lists based on another property using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have 2 different lists of an entity GraphData

```
class GraphData
{
DateTime date{get; set;}
double price{get;set;}
}
```

Now I have 2 different lists like List list1 and List list2

For example

list1 has followin values

```
1/1/2011,20.99
1/1/2012,45.67
31/03/2012,67.44
```

list2 has following values

```
1/1/2011,22.99
1/1/2012,90.67
31/03/2012,66.44
8/08/2013,70.77
```

Now I want to have a difference list List diffData

which calculates the difference between above 2 lists(list1,list2) only if the date is same

Result should be

```
1/1/2011,02.00(22.99-20.99)
1/1/2012,45.00(90.67-45.67)
31/03/2012,-1.00(66.44-67.44)
```

How can I do this using LINQ?

Comment: What should it return at the index where dates are not the same?

Comment: Similarly, if the two lists contain the same date but at different positions, do you want to pair them up or ignore them both?

Comment: Do you need Linq solution or simply c# code which fix that?

Comment: Can I not eliminate dates which are not same?

Comment: Any c# solution would do but as the list has lost of data I thought LINQ whould be better performance wise.Also I want to eleminate the dates which are not present in both the lists

Comment: You could CONCAT both list then do a GROUP BY. Within the grouping you would select the MIN and MAX value of price then combine that result into the desire output.

Comment: And I can assume that dates will be in an increasing order

Comment: "I thought LINQ whould be better performance wise"  -- there are really very rare cases when thinking about performance without first measuring it makes sense. This is not one of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
var q = from a in l1
    join b in l2 on a.date equals b.date
    select new GraphData()
    {
        date = a.date,
        price = b.price - a.price
    };
```

And if you always want a positive difference you can write `price = Math.Abs(a.price - b.price)`

Comment: Agreed, I think this is most likely what OP is trying to get at. (Although if dates are in increasing order like OP says, it may not be the most efficient way, but it's certainly the most succinct.)

Comment: @Rawling Yes, if the input is sorted a merge join would probably have somewhat better performance on large collection, but Linq only does hash joins, which have pretty good performance on larger collection also (sorted or not)

Answer (score 2):

```
list1.Join(list2, x => x.date, x => x.date, (x, y) => new GraphData {date = x.date, price = y.price - x.price});
```